# How to have class="selected" on same element with 2 different urls

Tags: php

As the title says.

I have this piece of code:

```
(strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'forum')) ? 'class="selected' : '';
```

Now this code has the element selected if the url is mysite.com/forum. But I wanna select the same element if the url is mysite.com/thread too.

I have tried:

```
(strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'forum' || 'thread')) ? 'class="selected' : '';
```

But then neither work, I get no error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have error on your syntax. See my answer for correct one

Answer (score 1):

The expression `'forum' || 'thread'` evaluates to `true` because non empty strings are truthy.

So your full expression becomes:

```
strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), true)
```

It's possible that `true` will be cast to a string because `strpos` wants a string. Which changes it to:

```
strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "1")
```

---

The expressions you're looking for is:

```
strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "forum") || strpos(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "thread")
```

This can still be improved: `htmlspecialchars` is not needed here and `strpos` can return `0` (which is falsy), so:

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "forum") !== false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "thread") !== false
```

Comment: I'm curious as to your suggestion of "You should use `strstr` instead", when the [docs for strstr](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) say "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead". IMO, the suggestion should be to use `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "forum") !== FALSE`, but I'd love to know your reasoning.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks, I knew about that, but I thought it was the other way around. Added a note for `strpos` returning `0` instead. I guess `strstr` also had that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
$contextPath = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

(strpos($contextPath, 'forum') || strpos(contextPath, 'thread')) ? 'class="selected' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if (preg_match('#^/(forum|thread)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) echo 'class="selected"'; ?>
```

Comment: This assumes the URL looks like `/forum/etc`. It will not match `/path/to/forum.php`

Comment: Urls in this question are `mysite.com/forum` and `mysite.com/thread`

Comment: That is also not matched by your regexp. Proof: https://www.debuggex.com/r/YjBNHdwNCYnxVEc6